# A constant function on MATLAB

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab

```
clear
clc

eta = 100;
a= 0;
xi=0.016;
axis([0 0.01 0 1.1]);
x = 0:0.0001:0.01;
N = -a+1.6*(1/(xi*eta));
y=N;
plot(x,y,'LineWidth',2);
set(gca,'FontSize',10);
```

Hi. I'd like to plot the function $N(x)$ (indeed, constant), on MATLAB, but the code above does not return any line on window. Why? Many thanks!

Comment: Is it possible and valid transport the question to https://scicomp.stackexchange.com? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to create an array of ones then you could do

```
y=ones(size(x));
```

or write

```
clear;
clc;

eta = 100;
a= 0;
xi=0.016;
axis([0 0.01 0 1.1]);
x = 0:0.0001:0.01;
temp = ones(size(x));
N = temp.*(-a+1.6*(1/(xi*eta)));
y=N;
plot(x,y,'LineWidth',2);
set(gca,'FontSize',10);
```

Though, it is extremely unclear why you are writing

```
N = -a+1.6*(1/(xi*eta));
```

when you could just write

```
N = 1;
```

or just make an array of ones and write

```
clear;
clc;

eta = 100;
a= 0;
xi=0.016;
axis([0 0.01 0 1.1]);
x = 0:0.0001:0.01;
y = ones(size(x));
plot(x,y,'LineWidth',2);
set(gca,'FontSize',10);
```

Comment: Many thanks, once I will change the values I did some unclear code, but many thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I like to write it

```
y=N+0*x;
```

Matlab automatically creates the array with the correct length. And, since you are multiplying it by 0, you create essencially a constant vector.

Comment: Many thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Y and X should be the same size:
y = N*size(x)

Comment: Many thanks! Putting y=N*size(x) I've not getting the result yet, instead I've got the error: Vectors must be the same length.

Comment: Since you would need to write y=N+0*x or write y=ones(size(x)).

Comment: Many thanks, it worked!